# mvc form does not post to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller

I have the following mvc login page that does not post to the controller.

LoginController

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Validate(AccountModels.LoginModel model)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            }

        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

cshtml

```
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Validate", "Login", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, @class = "user" }, FormMethod.Post))
           {
           <div class="form-group">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName, new { placeholder = "Enter username", @class = "form-control form-control-user", @title = "Please enter your username.", required = "required", @id = "inputUserName"})
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password, new { placeholder = "Enter password", @class = "form-control form-control-user", @title = "Please enter your password.", required = "required", @id = "inputPassword" })
                        </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                <div class="form-check">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => Model.RememberMe, new {@class="form-check-input custom-control-input", @id = "formCheck-1"})
                                            <label class="form-check-label custom-control-label" for="formCheck-1">Remember Me</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
  </div><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-white btn-user" type="submit">Login</button>
   }
```

When I submit the form it does not enter the controller action "Validate", what could cause this?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on your controller and tried submitting the form?

Comment: Yes, it does not reach that breakpoint

Comment: And your controller is called `LoginController`?

Comment: I found the issue, I had deny users in my web.config file.....